# Strange microphone problems at home

Tags: audio, microphone

I have this problem for over a year now, and it really boggles my mind. I will try to explain what my problem is as good as I can.

*To start off, I know about volume control etc.*

This basically all started when I wanted to record some gameplay footage from my PC. I needed a new PC anyway so I decided to build a decent system. I purchased all the parts, and for the motherboard I went with an Asus Maximus V Gene. I decided to start off with a normal headset from creative, a Alpha Tactical 3D, cheap.

Stage 1
The sound from the headset is great, but I noticed the recording sound was really really low. I thought it had to do with the 'normal' priced headset I bought. Well I went with is, and used audacity to boost my voice, and it went well. But it is quite a pain.

Stage 2
After a few months I decided to buy a new mic. I went with a YETI Blue USB mic, and the sound was absolutely amazing. Only downside, it picked up too much noise, typing etc. I really wanted a nice headset, so I returned the Yeti to the store.

Stage 3
Some weeks went by again, and decided to try something again, and I bought a Tritton 720+ headset. You plug the headset into a 7.1 decoder, and plug the decoder trough Optical to your PC. As soon as I connected it all up I could hear a strange static sound coming from the headset. The mic worked great actually, but the static was annoying. Now I looked this up, and what I was noticing was as they say a **ground loop**. Unfortunately I was so fed up, I bought the device to the store, actually I had to check it on my xbox or any other place in the home if the ground loop was there.

Stage 4
This time I bought a SteelSeries Siberia. This headset was exactly the same quality as my cheap creative headset I started off with. Mic quality was really low. At this time I also had a laptop, so I decided to try both headsets on my laptop. *On my laptop the mic quality was actually good!!!* So now I knew the problem was with my PC, and traded in the SteelSeries.

Stage 5
I thought the problem of this all was the Asus motherboard. I googled a little, and heard of people having audio defects in their boards, so I thought this was my problem. Now I bought a new board, and MSI Z77 MPOWER, and while I was at it I bought a new case. Just installed everything today, fresh Windows install, about an hour ago.

Well, the audio from the mic is still low, and on my laptop upstairs it is ok.

Anyone have an idea what my problem is. Could it have something to do with the ground loop thing, and what do I do about that.

Comment: here's a silly idea, I notice the lack of "microphone boost" in your question. Did you turn that up in your sound settings?

Comment: Yeah, but it only produces noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" I wanted to record some gameplay footage from my PC. "

Do you want to record just the game, or do you want a voice over.

Try this alternative to driving your self crazy with headsets and microphones.

There is software specifically designed to capture game play.  There are a number of software packages that do this.  Fraps for example will capture the video and audio internal without the need for a microphone.  Typically zero noise will exist.  There are numerous other packages that do the same thing.

I am drawing a blank to there names though.  Although FRAPS captures video and audio a free program like video lan from http://www.videolan.org can be used to strip the video or audio away if you so choose.

Although, I have yet tried it my self, this is another suggestion:

Dxtory from http://dxtory.com/v2-home-en.html

Comment: dxtory allows you to record your game as 1 audio track and a microphone as another.  This way you can apply noise cancelling affect and alter the volume of just your microphone if you feel like doing a commentary.